# Copying Page Layouts between tenancies in SP2013 Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, layouts, office-365

How does one move Page Layouts between tenancies in Sharepoint 2013 Online? I physically have the HTML file copied over and am able to select it from the page layouts dropdown in the ribbon, but I get an error (the generic "something went wrong") when I try to apply it.

I've tried updating the snippets with the generator in the new tenancy, but it's not helping.

Does anyone know generally how this is done? I do have a migration tool (Metavis), if that's significant.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an administrator account to perform this action. If you use a non-admin account you'll get your mentioned error, or what I got through testing on a non-admin account:

[image]

Set correct privilegies in Admin > Office 365 > Users and Groups. Select the name you want to make admin (with a global admin account) and select settings:

[image]

When you're done, the account can download (and upload) page layouts to the Master Page gallery located in /_catalogs/masterpage/

## Edited after real test

Here's my work

1. I downloaded a real Page Layout from my SharePoint Online environment A
2. I edited the Page Layout in notepad, changed the name and uploaded it to _catalogs/masterpage
3. I selected Page Layout content type and published a major version
4. I changed a new page Page Layout to my edited Page Layout - and published it with sucess.
5. I took the same edited page layout which was previously uploaded to SharePoint Online environment A and uploaded it to SharePoint Online environment B.
6. I selected Page Layout Content Type and published a major version.
7. I changed a new page Page Layout to my edited Page Layout - and published it with sucess.

No errors.

[image]

But you're using a migration tool, moving files from one environment to the other, without selecting content types during an upload operation. I think that the content type ID is pointing to SharePoint Online environment A instead of B which causes the error. Test by following my steps above and see the result.

Comment: Er, I do have admin access - I am able to successfully upload the page layout to the Master Page gallery, it's just when I apply it to a page that I get the error. Applying the page layout does work on the source tenancy, so I was thinking there was something unique to the database that SP puts into the page layout file that is not matching up when I move it.

Comment: @user2616620 Interesting! I'll give this a another shot tomorrow if you don't get a better answer.

Comment: That would be super amazing, thank you. I should note, I have tried swapping out the snippets with snippets generated by the new tenancy, and it didn't help. I thought perhaps they would have IDs associated with the database they came from.

Comment: @user2616620 I'm done with my tests, and I've come to this conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently we're moving the page layouts properly, there's just an issue with a piece of custom javascript that's causing the problem on the new tenancy... not clear on what went wrong there yet.

Answer (score -1):

You can copy the master pages and page layouts manually from the gallery and upload them on an other server. This is time consuming and I do not recommend it.

The best way to create, package and deploy your custom layout artifacts is using the Design Manager. Design Manager becomes available when you enable the publishing features on a SharePoint 2013 site.

With the Design Manager you can package all your master pages, page layouts, images, css, javascripts, etc... and upload the package to an other SharePoint (Online) server. The Design Manager takes care of the deployment of all the files.

There are plenty of online tutorials about the "Design Manager".